# Prove using the pigeonhole principle that there must be a power of 17 that ends in 00001

Tags: number-theory

I am stuck on this, and cannot advance. Prove with the pigeonhole principle that there must be a power of seventeen that ends in 00001.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: The claim is that $17^n \equiv 1 \bmod 10^m$ for some $n$. Show that there are two powers of $17$ that lie in the same residue class modulo $10^m$.

Comment: A further hint:  After you follow @franz suggestion (which works even if you change $17$ and $10^m$ to different numbers), you need to use the fact that $17$ and $10^m$ are relatively prime.

Answer (score 2):

Since the residue classes $\!\!\pmod{10^5}$ are just a finite number, the Dirichlet box principle ensures that $17^a\equiv 17^b\pmod{10^5}$ holds for two natural numbers fulfilling $a<b$ and $b-a\leq 10^5$.

Since $17$ and $10^5$ are coprime integers, the previous identity grants $17^{b-a}\equiv 1\pmod{10^5}$, and there is nothing left to prove.